# Does Android Content Provider authority definition break the DRY rule?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, dry

Android's `Content Provider` [must have](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#auth):

> At least one authority must be specified.

So for example in Google's samples [android-BasicSyncAdapter AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter/blob/master/Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) there is

```
<provider
    android:name=".provider.FeedProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.android.basicsyncadapter"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Then to implement this CP one need to define the same String inside the CP like in [android-BasicSyncAdapter FeedProvider.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter/blob/8210761ee67e06210d14ce913b2d82618cee0bb7/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicsyncadapter/provider/FeedProvider.java) `CONTENT_AUTHORITY`

```
public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.basicsyncadapter";
```

As we have to define this String twice, isn't this basically breaking the DRY rule - if I change it in one place, I have to remember to change it somewhere else as well.

Comment: hmmm, i wish i had your problems... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't have to specify the authority multiple times. In our [OpenTasks Provider](https://github.com/dmfs/opentasks-provider/blob/master/src/org/dmfs/provider/tasks/TaskProvider.java#L163) we load the authority at runtime from the manifest.

The basic idea is this:

```
Context context = getContext();
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
ProviderInfo providerInfo = packageManager.getProviderInfo(
    new ComponentName(context, this.getClass()),
    PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS | PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
String authority = providerInfo.authority;
```

On Android 2.2 you have to take some extra efforts since the method `getProviderInfo` is not present yet.

Optionally you could just specify the authority in a String resource and refer to it from the Manifest like so:

```
<provider
    android:name=".provider.FeedProvider"
    android:authorities="@string/authority"
    android:exported="false" />
```

In your content provider you load the authority as usual:

```
String authority = getContext().getString(R.string.authority);
```

It's a bit more difficult if your content provider serves multiple authorities, but that's probably not a good idea anyway.

### Update to follow up with your comment:

I don't see a problem with providing a `Context` to the contract.

Instead of writing something like

```
Cursor c = contentProvider.query(MyContract.Items.CONTENT_URI,
    null, null, null, null);
```

You would just write

```
Cursor c = contentProvider.query(MyContract.Items.itemsUri(getContext()),
    null, null, null, null);
```

with

```
public final interface MyContract {

    // ... lots of other tables ...

    public final static class Items {
       public final static String CONTENT_PATH = "items";

       // all the contract definitions

       public final static Uri itemsUri(Context context) {
           return new Uri.Builder()
               .scheme("content")
               .authority(context.getString(R.string.authority)).
               .path(CONTENT_PATH)
               .build();
       }
}
```

There is not much of a difference, except that it can be even more convenient when you also need to add an ID:

```
Cursor c = contentProvider.query(MyContract.Items.itemUri(getContext(), myItemId),
    null, null, null, null);
```

Passing a `Context` to these static methods is usually not a problem since you need the Context anyway to get a `ContentResolver`.

An advantage of this technique is that your code is completely independent of the actual authority and you can easily import the `ContentProvider` as a library into a different project with a different authority and you don't need to change a single line of your code.

Btw I prefer the first version (loading the authority from the Manifest) since you don't even need a String resource in that case. You can just [inject `${applicationId}`](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html#inject-values) and never touch it again.

The following manifest snippet guarantees that your authority is unique for each app that you import it in:

```
<provider
    android:name=".provider.FeedProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.myauthority"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: there's one problem with strings resources solution - you have to use getContext() - in class which extends Content Provider it's easy but if you have to know this authority value in for example Contract class then you're making it Context dependent which is weak

Comment: Updated my answer to elaborate on you concern.

Comment: Looks good, I'll try it - but why Contract is an interface - any good reason for that?

Comment: You can make it a class. There is no specific reason. I just think it's more adequate since a Contract is basically some other form of interface (even if you never instantiate it as such).