# Accessing data from Custom Content Providers

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I've two content provider based apps A and B. Both have their own content providers and are setup for reading data from A and B and vice versa. Everything works fine when the other app is in background. But couldn't find another content provider if the app is killed or not present in background. For example, App B wants to read data from App A. 'B' can read data from 'A' successfully when 'A' is running in background, but gave fatal error (Match uri not found) if 'A' is not running in background.

Any thoughts ?

[EDIT]
I'm getting the same issue as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883193/android-contentresolver-query-sometimes-not-starting-contentprovider-process). 
I've this in both apps' manifest:

```
   <provider
        android:name="MyContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.${applicationId}-provider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    </provider>
```

This the error I'm getting:

> Writing exception to parcel
>                                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported URI(Query): content://com.example.appA-provider/appA
>                                                                                   at com.example.provider.MyContentProvider.query(MyContentProvider.java:142)
>                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1007)
>                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:218)
>                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:461)

Note: This only happens when another app is not in background, otherwise it works as expected (can read each other's data fine).

[EDIT 2]
Here's code for MyContentProvider:

```
package com.example.provider;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;


public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    private static final int ALL_ENTRIES = 1;
    private static final int SINGLE_ENTRY = 2;

    private String mAuthority = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
    private static UriMatcher uriMatcher;

    public Uri CONTENT_URI= null;

    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    }

    public MyContentProvider() {}

    public void init(String packageName, String authority) {
        if (authority == null) {
            setAuthority(packageName, true);
        } else {
            setAuthority(authority, false);
        }

        uriMatcher.addURI(getAuthority(), TABLE_NAME, ALL_ENTRIES);
        uriMatcher.addURI(getAuthority(), TABLE_NAME + "/#", SINGLE_ENTRY);
        CONTENT_URI =
                Uri.parse("content://" + getAuthority() + "/" + TABLE_NAME);
    }

    private void setAuthority(String packageName, boolean isPackageName) {
        if (isPackageName) {
            mAuthority = packageName + ".myprovider";
        } else {
            mAuthority = packageName;
        }
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return mAuthority;
    }

    public Uri getContentUri() {
        return CONTENT_URI;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

    //Return the MIME type corresponding to a content URI
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {

        if (uri == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Content uri is null: " + uri);
        }
        if (uriMatcher == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Match URI: " + uri);
        }

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case ALL_ENTRIES:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd." + getAuthority() + "." + TABLE_NAME;
            case SINGLE_ENTRY:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd." + getAuthority() + "." + TABLE_NAME;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        Uri _uri = null;
        long id = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case ALL_ENTRIES:
            case SINGLE_ENTRY:
                id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                _uri = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI (insert): " + uri);
        }

        return _uri;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        String id = null;

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case ALL_ENTRIES:
                queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
                cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
                        selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                break;
            case SINGLE_ENTRY:
                queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
                id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                if (id != null && !id.isEmpty()) {
                    queryBuilder.appendWhere(TABLE_NAME + "=" + id);
                }

                cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
                        selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI(Query): " + uri);
        }

        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Match uri not found` does not say anything, post your code and the complete stack trace

Comment: Check both manifest <provider> tag and consider putting the content provider code in a library?

Comment: @Pomagranite: I've put <provider> code above. Yes, I'm using content provider code as library.

Comment: @pskink: updated the post with <provider> code and stack trace. Its not much, but this all what I got. I don't see any issue with provider's code because other app can fetch data successfully. I suspect that I'm missing something in <provider> configuration.

Comment: What does the code of MyContentProvider look like?

Comment: @bryan: added MyContentProvider code. worth to mention again that everything works great when both apps are running (one in foreground while another is in background).

Comment: The "Unsupported URI" message seems to be your own. Ask yourself if that is a valid `Uri` or not. If not, the problem is on the client side. If it is valid, the problem is on the provider side for failing to recognize it.

Comment: Do you ever call `init(String, String)`? If so, when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not initialize the content provider from somewhere else in your code like this, as the ContentProvider might be the first (or only) component of your app that's instantiated.

However, you can read the authority dynamically from the Manifest or a String resource. In my answer on [Does Android Content Provider authority definition break the DRY rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713033/does-android-content-provider-authority-definition-break-the-dry-rule/36732030#36732030) I outlined how we that in our OpenTasks-Provider.

Comment: I'm trying to use library for content provider. I'm expecting calling init () should initialize app that's using content provider library to create it's own cp. Offcourse it's not working. Is it possible at all to have cp wrapped as a library. How it can be initialized dynamically?

Comment: Of course you can ship a ContentProvider in a library. That's what we do with our TaskProvider too (at present we ship it as a jar, but we're planning to switch to an aar. Check out how we "auto-initialize" our [TaskProvider](https://github.com/dmfs/opentasks-provider/blob/master/src/org/dmfs/provider/tasks/TaskProvider.java#L159)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a call to `init()` in content provider. Is it only called from elsewhere as part of the application's start ?

If so that may explains why the content provider fails when the application is not already started : In this case the `UriMatcher` is empty and the `switch` in the `query()` method falls back to `default` witch throws the `IllegalArgumentException`.

You should either call `init()` in `onCreate()` or fully initialize the `UriMatcher` in the static initializer.

Comment: I want to initialize(adding Uris) UriMatcher dynamically. Is it possible for Content provider to read its authority from Manifest at all?

Comment: `getContext()` is useable in `onCreate()` (not in the constructor). The context gives you access to a lot of informations. In your case, doesn't `getPackageManager()`, `getPackageName()`, ... provide what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the authority as

```
private void setAuthority(String packageName, boolean isPackageName) {
        if (isPackageName) {
            mAuthority = packageName + ".myprovider";
        } else {
            mAuthority = packageName;
        }
    }
```

So your mAuthority is either `com.example.provider` or `com.example.provider.myprovider`

However, you have defined authorities in the manifest as

```
android:authorities="com.example.${applicationId}-provider"
```

that is `com.example.appA-provider`