# How to configure content provider to be listening to requests

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

How can I configure a custom android content provider to be listening to requests to it ? What happens when a query is made to custom content provider ? Does it invoke the app containing custom content provider to read data ? Does custom content provider should be running in background to fulfill requests made from another app?

Here's the query made to custom content provider:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.example.provider/table1");
        ContentProviderClient contentResolver = getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(uri);
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: One question a time. Please read the [FAQ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I configure a custom android content provider to be listening to requests to it ?

Have [the `<provider>` element for it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ProviderElement).

> Does it invoke the app containing custom content provider to read data ?

Yes.

> Does custom content provider should be running in background to fulfill requests made from another app?

No. A process will be forked for the app if one is needed.

Comment: Glad to hear from you ! I've this specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223456/accessing-data-from-custom-content-providers

Comment: I've custom content provider working fine when its in background, but client app (using this CP) failing when CP is not present in background.

Comment: you mentioned that a process will be forked. do you know what configuration for <provider> is required to enable that. I've my code in above link in comment.

Comment: @bianca: "do you know what configuration for <provider> is required to enable that" -- there is no "configuration". It happens by default. In fact, I do not know of any way to stop it, other than disabling the component outright (`android:enabled="false"` or `setComponentEnabledSetting()` in Java).

Comment: that's what I read in documentation that it should be available by default. But it only works when it's running in background. Any clue why it's not working for me?

Comment: @bianca: Your other question shows that it is working just fine. Your code is executing, and you are throwing your own exception. Now, you need to determine why you are throwing your own exception, and whether that indicates a problem on the client side or on the provider side.

Comment: I get this error when I kill app with content provider and run client app to query data from it.

Comment: So, client app only find that content provider when it's actually running in background

Comment: @bianca: Somebody, in the code that you posted to your other question, wrote `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI(Query): " + uri);`. The client app can find that content provider, because that is the exception that is being thrown. After all, you cannot throw an exception unless the code is running. So, the `query()` method on the provider is being invoked. *Why* the `query()` method is not recognizing that `Uri` is for you to debug.